# Improve route layout in jsPlumb

Tags: layout, jsplumb

I have a quite easy layout of blocks, please see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzh5b.png.
I was wondering if I can instruct jsPlumb to draw the connections in a more elegant way.
The connections leaving the fork node could be spread better. I would like to see the bottom two connections to follow a similar path than the top two. Same for the join node.

Is this possible?

This is my current definition of a connector:

```
var stateMachineConnector = {
    connector : [ "Flowchart", {
        stub : [ 20, 20 ],
        cornerRadius : 5,
        gap : 2
    } ],
    paintStyle : {
        lineWidth : 2,
        strokeStyle : "#777"
    },
    hoverPaintStyle : {
        strokeStyle : "#dbe300"
    },
    endpoint : "Blank",
    anchor : "Continuous",
    maxConnections : 1,
    overlays : [ [ "PlainArrow", {
        location : 1,
        width : 12,
        length : 12
    } ] ]
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Michiel

Comment: Each `Connector` object has a `userSuppliedSegments` parameter which can be written to using the `.setPath()` method, see the bottom of this file: https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/blob/master/src/connectors-flowchart.js.

Comment: Great! This will probably do!

Comment: Hey mvermand, I am facing the same Problem. Did you find a solution for it?